# How to create Excel data model relationships using Apache POI?

Tags: apache-poi, openxml

I'm trying to create an excel file with a data model and relationships between tables.

The equivalent of manually setting relations in Excel via GUI:

`Data -> Relationships`

When extracting the `.xlsx` file I can see that information stored in the `xl/workbook.xml` file however I cannot find it in apache POI.

Is there a way to specify data model relationships using Apache POI (poi-ooxml:4.1.2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: It's not possible in Apache POI

Solution: I've created a .xlsm file template with macros that create relationships after the file has been opened in Excel if there are no relationships defined in the woorkbook. I've stored the information about relationships within the excel file in a separate, hidden sheet and use that as an input to excel macros.